# AngularJS add/removeClass does nothing?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add and remove a class on button click. Unfortunately nothing I do seems to achieve this. The class never changes no matter what I do.

Here is what I am trying to change;

```
<div ng-controller="navbarCollaspeCtrl">
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent">

<button class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" ng-click="changeClass()" href="" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navToggle" aria-controls="navToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

And here is the Angular part;

```
.controller('navbarCollaspeCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {

$scope.changeClass = function() {

    var el = document.getElementById('mainNav');
    $element.removeClass(el, "navbar-transparent");
    $element.addClass(el, "navbar-primary");
    console.log(el);

}
```

}])

The 'navbar-transparent does not get removed. And navbar-primary never gets added. Any thoughts?

Comment: $element is not navbar. You're not using el. You're not using [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) properly

Comment: But I only need to move the class from that element, I want to remove it using the ID? In AngularJS docs it says removeClass(DOM Element, Class Name) ?

Comment: It's unlikely that it says something like that, because it just replicates jQuery API and doesn't work this way. It's something like `angular.element(el).removeClass("navbar-transparent")`. And the proper way is how the answer suggests it.

Comment: Try to bind the variable with ng-bind and with ng-if you can show or remove it from DOM.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to manipulate DOM elements like this for simple scenarios like this one (this is more of a jQueryish approach). Instead create a variable and bind to it to toggle the style.

**Html**

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg" {{transparent ? 'navbar-transparent': ''}}">
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('navbarCollaspeCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
   $scope.transparent = false;
}]);
```

You can also use `ng-class` directive.

Comment: There are two `class` attributes. The first one will be overridden. One of them should be `ng-class`.

Comment: @estus - yes. I have merged the classes. Thanks.